# Moving multidimensional array pointers in C - Incompatible Types

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, types, multidimensional-array

Here is a very simple example of what I am trying to do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  char a[2][2][5] = { {"hello", "world"}, {"again", "test1"}};

  a[1] = a[0];

  printf("a[0][0]: %s\n", a[0][0]);
  printf("a[0][1]: %s\n", a[0][1]);
  printf("a[1][0]: %s\n", a[1][0]);
  printf("a[1][1]: %s\n", a[1][1]);
}
```

I expect it to print:
a[0][0]: hello
a[0][1]: world
a[1][0]: hello
a[1][1]: world

Instead all I get is `error: incompatible types in assignment`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot assign arrays, you should copy them (using memcpy or memmove)

```
memcpy(a[1], a[0], sizeof(a[0]));
```

Also, each of your string is of size 6, not 5 (there is an implicit null terminator).

Comment: Thanks, forgot about the implicit null char, but this was obviously a contrived example :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign arrays. However, you can assign structs:

```
struct Foo
{
    char data[2][5];
};

struct Foo b, a = { { "hello", "world" } };
b = a;

struct Foo c[2] = { { { "hello", "world" } }, { {"again", "test1"} } };
c[1] = c[0];
```